# Proxy after Tor in Tails

Tags: tails, web-proxy

A lot of sites are blocking Tor IP or I must fight with capchta. 
So can I use proxy after Tor in Tails? For connection tails->tor->proxy->www.
If not proxy, maybe ssh tunnel is possible?

Comment: From what I understand that would be defeating the purpose of tails and tor it would end up looking like. Tails(Proxy)(Tor)--->(Tor)(Proxy)--->Tor(Exit Node)--->Proxy(Exit)--->(Website)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a web-based proxy to avoid being blocked when a website notices your tor exit node IP address. I tested this particular proxy with two different websites that block tor traffic, and it worked fine. Because you don't mess with any Tor Browser settings you are getting the requested
 Tor -> Proxy -> Clearnet

https://hide.me/en/proxy

One thing to keep in mind, the proxy could probably monitor whatever you do over it, but they won't have any idea who you are since you're coming to them through Tor. Except for any identifying info you reveal in your browsing that they may be monitoring.